# Google mail servers rejecting emails to group/ alias as it believes these emails are auto-responses

Tags: gmail

I have a Auto forward rule on group email address. This Group Email doesn't accept Auto-generated emails such as Vacation Email.

It Throws following Error:

> Technical details of permanent failure: Your email looks like an auto-response so is not being accepted.

How to overcome this Scenario?